# Coauthors for questions or answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A number of papers in TCS have coauthors. It would be nice to allow coauthors to ask a question or to give an answer. Is is just technically too difficult or are there other reasons not to have this feature?

P.S. This question is likely to apply to most sites of StackExchange. Please feel free to move it to the appropriate level.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just too difficult to do on the Stack Exchange platform.  It seems unlikely that a special feature like this will be implemented just for TCS.SE, given that it's unlikely to be widely used on other sites (and, frankly, unlikely to be widely used even on this site).

If you had someone collaborate with you on forming the question (or your answer), why not add a note at the bottom of your question/answer that acknowledges them appropriately?  That seems like a reasonable workaround within the existing system.